# Renomear todos os arquivos do diretório onde tem "u0026" para "e"

Tags: php, batch

Estou com mais de dois mil arquivos com o "u0026" no meio dos nomes (no caso seria o &) e preciso de um script que pode sem em php ou batch para renomear todos mantendo o nome original trocando apenas esse "u0026" por "e", estou usando o Windows 10 e o diretório de todos os arquivos é o mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

em python pode ser?

```
import os
[os.rename(f, f.replace('u0026', 'e')) for f in os.listdir('.') if not f.startswith('.')]
```

Este script vai substituir a string 'u0026' por 'e' em todos os arquivos da pasta que for rodado.

---

Powershell tambem rola já q ta com o W10, executa ele na pasta que deseja renomear os arquivos.

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "u0026","e"}
```

Comment: infelizmente não, não o tenho na maquina

Comment: talvez a opção com powershell.. olha ali

Comment: pelo power pode ser, no "dir" a frente dele teria que adicionar o diretório, certo?

Comment: A intenção de ajudar é boa, mas é importante notar as tags que são [php] e [batch], ou seja prompt de comando do Windows.

Comment: @LaércioLopes eu vi as tags, no entanto ofereci uma opção que seria mais sensata julgando que ele vai executar a nível de OS. então PHP seria um pouco demais para a tarefa em mãos. E o código em python é beem mais simplees do que em bash. Nem sempre o que o OP pede é o que ele precisa. Estamos aqui pra ajudar..

Comment: @JoãoVictor o comando Dir vai listar os arquivos para o proximo comando é só executar ele como esta na pasta desejada.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado